# is it possible to execute dotnet exe on linux with node.js child process?

Tags: .net, linux, node.js, exec, child-process

I have an exe, what was created with dotnet. I have an rhc server, where I want to run this exe, and catch the oputput of it (with child-process). But I have a folowing error:

> cannot execute binary file

I understand that is not executeable on linux, but is there any solution to solve this, without rewrite the exe, or change os? Are there any node package, what can solve this?

Very thanx for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible without recompiling the exe. If you had the sources, you could compile them with [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) and invoke mono from node.

Comment: It's fantastic, I have the sources offcourse. I'm not a .net developert, but I will try this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Wine for launching windows binaries in linux. It is not 100% compatible with all windows libraries but it supports a lot of applications. So instead of trying to execute exe directly from node, you can call the wine command to launch the exe for you.

You cna get more info on wine at http://www.winehq.org

Comment: Very thx for this, but unforunately, I think, I can't use it on my rhc server. :( But it's interesting anyway.